# ruby on rails photo upload problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, show, photo

Hallo

rails version 2.3.5

I'm learning rails and I run into a problem.

I'm doing some nesting forms from the railscasts tutorials. I changed the text area into a data field to upload photos and everything is working.

Now i have to display the uploaded pictures and i simply can't do it. I Tried everything I could find on the net but nothing worked.

PROBLEM

I have the Article controller which handles the article CRUD. 
inside the article new form there is nested a form for uploading images.

article controller

```
  def code_image 
      @image_data = Photo.find(params[:id]) 
      @image = @image_data.binary_data 
      send_data(@image, :type => @image_data.content_type,
                        :filename => @image_data.filename,
                        :disposition => 'inline') 
  end
```

photo model

```
def image_file=(input_data)
self.filename = input_data.original_filename 
self.content_type = input_data.content_type.chomp 
self.binary_data = input_data.read 
end
```

articles/show.html.erb

```
<%=h @article.title %>
<%=h @article.body %>
<% for photos in @article.photos %>
<%= image_tag(url_for({:action => 'code_image', 
:id => @article.photos.id})) -%>
<% end %>
```

articles/_formnew.html.erb

```
 <% form_for (:article, @article,
:url => {:action=>'create'}, :html=>        
{:multipart=>true}) do |f| %>
```

```
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %><br /><br />

<%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_area :body, :style => 'width: 600px;' %><br /><br />

<% f.fields_for :photos do |builder|%>

<%= builder.label :content, "Photo"%><br />
<%= builder.file_field :image_file %><br />

<% end %>
<br />
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to view the image directly by going to the URL routed to your code_image action?  Does your Photo record look to be complete/correct when viewed using the Rails console?  What about when you look in the photos table in your database?  Answering these questions should help you isolate where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but if somebody stumbles across it, this page helped me:
http://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/

Also, to display the image, you can just use:

```
image_tag [model].[paperclip_attachment].url
```

eg:`image_tag trip_image.photo.url`